# Using a certificate in the proof of NP hardness

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat, reductions

Say I wanted to determine that the problem of membership in some language $L \subseteq \{0, 1\}^*$ is NP-hard.  Say that I have a reduction $r: \{\text{set of quantifier free formulas} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^*$ such that for all QF formula $\phi$, there exists a polynomial(in the size of $\phi$) certificate $C \in \{0, 1\}^*$ such that $\phi$ is satisfiable iff $r(\phi)^\frown C \in L$ (this is the concatenation operation) and for all $y \neq C$, we know that $r(\phi)^\frown C \not\in L$.

My goal was to prove that the problem of determining whether $x \in L$ is NP hard by reducing SAT to this problem. My colleague claims that the above is a sufficient proof of NP hardness, but I don't fully understand their rationale. Does this work? If so why?

Comment: In a word, no. Though I admit that the condition on uniqueness of the certificate makes it difficult to construct counterexamples (but it’s a simple exercise to show they exist assuming $\mathrm{NP = UP\ne P}$).